# Is there an always existing, known Unix path string guaranteed to name an always empty directory?

Tags: unix, stat, readdir

Under many, most, or maybe all Unix file systems, if you iterate over the links in a directory, there will usually/always be at least two, one pointing to the current directory ("./"), and one back-pointing to the parent directory ("../").  Except maybe for the root, which would have only the first of these two links.

But it might be that this is not true under some other file systems that purport to comport with most Unix conventions (but don't quite).

Is there a directory somewhere in a Unix file system guaranteed to always be an empty directory and whose link count can always be read using, e.g., stat() or equivalent?

If so, one can check the link count and expect it to be 2.  Or perhaps something else, which would allow a program to adjust its behavior accordingly.

Comment: "Except maybe for the root, which would have only the first of these two links." This is not true, even the root directory has a `..`, however it points to itself.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard directory which is always empty -- but you could create one, if you needed to. One easy way to do this would be using the `mkdtemp()` function.

However, there is no guarantee that all directories will be using the same file system. For instance, if a FAT filesystem is mounted, directories corresponding to that file system may behave differently from other ones.